# how to check whether a filter in angular js has returned any data or not in the search

Tags: angularjs, filter

I am very new to angular js.I want to know how can I call a function based on the filter search in angular js.I need to call a function in the controller when the search based on the filter returns no values.

```
<li ng-repeat="test in test_list | filter: test_id">
                    {{ test}} 
                 </li>
```

When the list of {{test}} is null I want to call a function in the controller.

This might be very easy for you guys.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Watch the filtered value: `$scope.$watch('test_list | filter: test_id', function (filteredList) { if (filteredList.length === 0) { doWhateverYouWantHere(); } })`

Comment: can you plz ellaborate little bit more and mention how to use it in the view as well.Thanks in advance

Comment: Try this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28766725/to-check-whether-any-value-returned-by-filter-in-angular-js/28768208#28768208

Comment: that didnt work..that question was posted by me only Vinay :)

Answer (score 4):

```
<li ng-repeat="test in results = (test_list | filter: test_id)">
                    {{ test}} 
                 </li>
```

You will then be able to access $scope.results.length

If you need to display a message when there is no results add

```
<li ng-show="results.length == 0">No results</li>
```

If you want to check the length in the controller theres several ways you can do it... this is only two...

```
<input type="text" id="test_id" ng-model="test_id" ng-change="controllerOnChangeFunction()"/>
```

In your controller

```
$scope.controllerOnChangeFunction = function() {
    if ($scope.results.length == 0) {
         //do stuff here
    }
}
```

or alternatively, in your controller (Keep in mind this watch will evaluate more often than you need it too.

```
$scope.watch(
    function(){
        return $scope.results.length
    }, 
    function(newVal){
        if (newVal == 0) { 
             // do you stuff here
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: then how to call a function ? if result is zero ?

Comment: same question...then how to call a function  if result is zero ?

Comment: `test in results = (test_list | filter: test_id)` did the trick, thanks I didn't know that!